# How should I do lowering the minimum SDK version?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-api-levels

I'm working on an Anrdoid app. It's almost finished. I've just noticed that the `minSdkVersion` is set to 21. Maybe I forgot it when I created the project. I'd like to lower it, because the app's users will likely to have older devices.

I don't think it's good idea to change the `minSdkVersion` to ~10, sit back, and hope it will compile and run fine in the future.

My idea was that I could check all the methods used in the project, their minimum API level, so I could know what I have to replace with alternatives. However, the project is a bit large. Searching for all methods' documentation one by one would take a lot of time.

Is it possible to automatically list the Android API specific methods used in my project, and their API level? Or somehow detect the highest API level that is required by an used method? Android Studio knows these numbers, it can fetch the documentation too. Or, is it safe to change the `minSdkVersion` and `targetSdkVersion` to a lower API level to know which methods aren't supported in an older device, and after I fix all errors/warnings the IDE will show me, will my app run fine?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Android Studio will give you warnings when you use methods that require a higher sdk version than your specified `minSdkVersion`. You can access the whole list of these warnings for the complete project by leveraging the Analyze -> Code Cleanup functionality. So what you can do:

1. Lower the `minSdkVersion`.
2. Click Analyze -> Code Cleanup in Android Studio. Select "Whole Project"
3. The relevant errors are part of these sections:

   - Android Lint: Correctness -> Attribute unused on older versions
   - Android Lint: Correctness -> Calling new methods on older versions
   - Android Lint: Correctness -> using inlined constants on older versions
   - Android Lint: Internationalization -> Right-to-left text compatibility issues

By trying different version numbers you can see how many changes are necessary. To decide for the correct `minSdkVersion`, you might want to consider the [Android API level device stats](https://developer.android.com/about/dashboards/index.html).

So a **strategy for deciding** for a `targetSdkVersion` or `minSdkVersion` typically looks like this: You set the `targetSdkVersion` to the highest version number that you have tested your app with. The `minSdkVersion` should be set to a lower value - low enough so enough devices are supported, but high enough so there are not to many version specific workarounds necessary. Find details about these two values [in the Android documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-sdk-element.html).

Comment: This isn't totally safe. Although I asked about only methods, there was a problem in an XML layout that might be important too, but wasn't catched using the Code Cleanup: https://i.stack.imgur.com/hBA2Z.png

Comment: Thanks for the hint, I updated the answer accordingly.